# Automatic work flow design

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am implementing an MVC application in that I have a requirement like render a dynamic work flow inside a web page. Below is the example scenario:

I have a task which has 10 steps to complete, I completed 4 steps only in that entire task. I need to show all 10 steps in a diagram (in this decision making scenarios also applicable) and highlight only steps which I completed in color.

Is there any tool available in asp.net/ajax/jquery what ever it may be.

Comment: please help me on this any body :(

Comment: You need to learn some logics of programmation...

Answer (score 0):

You can Try JsPlumb. There is a demo for state machine (workflow). JsPlumb gives only UI, you need to write your logic in to change color etc...